# What does this Java main() method represent?

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

The main() method in the following Java program is a text rebus.  What does it represent?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class WhatDoesMainRepresent {
    private static HashSet<Obj> hashSet = new HashSet<Obj>();
    private static AffineTransform e = new AffineTransform();

    static {
        hashSet.add(new Obj());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hashSet.add(new Obj());
        e.rotate(Math.PI);
        {}
    }

    private static class Obj {
        public int hashCode() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Hints:

> 1. The AffineTransform object is named `e` for a reason.
>  2. The `hashSet.add(new Obj())` line in the main() method represents a single word that is a verb.  (So far that word has not been mentioned.)

Comment: That hash method might have just made be cry...

Comment: I am now tempted to do a near identical puzzle where a string object "u" is placed with an object with a hashCode of 2. And getting rid of the affine transform.

Comment: @pacoverflow does it have something to do with Coffee and Pie? Like dipping Cracked Coffee Cake in Coffee at Starbucks?

Comment: @kanchirk Nothing to do with coffee and pie.

Comment: Is that verb 'spin'?

Comment: @CodeNewbie It is not spin.

Comment: If you rotate an `e` by 180º you get a weird looking `g`...

Comment: wait, no it doesn't...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It represents

> Kaleidoscope

Reasoning:

> The second add will have the object "collide" with the first on the hashset since they have the same hash code. e rotated 180 degees is "a". The empty curly braces are a new "scope". Collide+a+scope = kaleidoscope.

Comment: I think you got it one note, the e rotated is definitely intended to be a schwa. But I like it.

Comment: Good job.  I was definitely thinking of a schwa for the rotated `e` (it was [another puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17806/4450) on this site).  The `a` works almost as well, although it's dependent on the font.

Answer (score 14):

I shame myself with this guess if it turns out to be wrong, but I suspect the text is the idiom

> [been around the block once or twice](http://esl.about.com/od/vocabularyreference/a/express_around.htm)

The reasoning being:

> Every key/value pair in a hash map is stored in a *bin* determined by its hash code. In this case the hashcode for all objects of the `Obj` class is identical, meaning such objects are stored in the same bin.
> The `e.rotate(Math.PI)` statement performs a useless 180° inversion. The transform will therefore turn its operand *around*. The `{}` represents an empty *block*.
> The static statement and initial statement in `main` adds an object to the same *bin* once and then twice.
> Hence: *bin* *around* the *block* *once or twice*.
> After typing this out, I realize how indescribably bad this pun is. I truly hope this isn't the correct answer. :P

Comment: No need to worry, that's not the correct answer.  :)  +1 for a nice explanation though.

Comment: After reading that explanation, it's kinda hard to believe this isn't correct. +1

Comment: @Geobits Well the puzzle does specify that the rebus is the main method, so the static statement won't be a part of the answer, so "or twice" isn't really valid.

Comment: If the static statement isn't part of the answer, what is its purpose? The code will function the same without it.

Comment: I think you're right about the "spin around" line.  I suspect the last block is more of a "do nothing" than a "block", though.

Comment: @IanMacDonald The static statement provides setup for main().  I think that if COTO's answer were the correct answer, then both hashMap.put() calls could be in main() - there'd be no need for a static initialization block.

Comment: @pacoverflow: Two questions: 1) Is the fact that you're using a hash map with `null` key instead of a hash set significant? (Strictly speaking, storing null values in a hash map is evil code.) 2) Is the `hashMap.put(new Obj(), null)` statement "replace"? That was my initial assumption, but I can't think of any English expressions or idioms containing "replace".

Comment: @COTO `null` is the value, the two new Obj instances are the keys, with separate identities, so the second won't replace the first.

Comment: @Kevin: Because hashCode returns 1 for all instances of Obj, when used as a key, the values will replace each other in the HashMap. In this case, it replaces `null` with `null`.

Comment: @IanMacDonald As I understand it, the hashCode is used for performance, to find the item in the HashMap's internal buckets, not to identify an individual key within those buckets. As a quick test I just pasted the code to an editor, printed the size of the map and after the second `put` there are two items in it.

Comment: @Kevin I suppose it would also require `equals` to return true. But then I wonder what the point of including it at all was...

Comment: @pacoverflow: I overlooked the fact that you hadn't overridden `equals`. So possibly "two in a bucket", "twice in the bucket", "toss in the bucket", then possibly "turns over", "around", "dumps out", "overturns", then possibly "block", "empty", "nothing", "empty-handed". And because it's a rebus, "over", "under", "with", etc. can always play a part. A-aaaand... I've still got nothing. :P

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is:

> Love story

Reasoning:

`hashSet.add(new Obj());`

> Here an object is being stored in a hash set [STORE]

`e.rotate(Math.PI);`

> Here the object e is having a 180 degree rotation applied [E ABOUT]

`{}`

> This is an empty block, so this code does nothing, or love as nothing can be termed in tennis for example [LOVE]

So putting it together we have:

> STORE E ABOUT LOVE i.e. STORY ABOUT LOVE or LOVE STORY

Comment: +1 for a nice try, but if this is the correct answer, then the static initialization block is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @pacoverflow Hmm yes good point

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Much Ado About Nothing

Building quite heavily COTO's answer:

> There's much code before the `main()`, but then it adds (sounds vaguely like "Ado") one more element, a new Obj object, to the collection, so it doesn't have none or one, but rather, much content.
>
>  The `e.rotate(Math.PI)` being "about".
>
>  And the empty code block `{}` being "Nothing".

Comment: Sorry that's not it.  If I were going for "ado", I would have put in a do-while statement.  :)

Comment: Ah well...  That was much ado about nothing, then...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is what you're after, but it could look like part of one school of thought for the perfect barbecue:

> add another one (second distinct Obj object: 'another', hashCode: 'one') to the block (static initialiser: 'block', also HashSet: reference to barbecue grids or the deliberate style of burn marks on the meat after cooking), turn it over once at the natural point, i.e. half way through cooking (e: base of *natural* logs, rotate by $\pi$: turn around), then just let it sit i.e. do nothing until it is done (empty brace = nop: do nothing , end of main(): 'done').

Comment: But is this answer *well done*?

Comment: @MarkN Compared to the other answers so far, perhaps *rare*.